# Unable to view Apache log in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have installed ELK stack on windows and configured Logstash to read an Apache Log file. I cant seem to see the output in Elasticsearch. I am very new to ELK stack.

**Environment Setup**
Elasticsearch: http://localhost:9200/
Logstash :
Kibana : http://localhost:5601/

All 3 applications above are running as a service.

I have created a file called "**logstash.conf**" to read apache logs in **"C:\Elk\logstash\conf\logstash.conf"** with the following :

```
input {
file {
path => "C:\Elk\apache.log"
start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output {
elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
```

I then restarted my Logstash service and now wish to see if elasticsearch is indexing the content of my log. How do i go about doing this ?

Comment: Does Logstash have error logs?

Comment: I cannot see any error log files in the Logstash directory.

Comment: Your grok filter is wrong, see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and the null filter does not exist, use the [drop filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html) instead

Comment: Also you can start Logstash with powershell, with the -f option to give your configuration file. That way you'll see the error form Logstash

Comment: And are you sure about the `&gt;` ? I have never seen that used for Logstash configuration on either Linux or Windows

Comment: @baudsp thanks for your response. I executed the -f logstash.conf command in PowerShell and got the following error : "-f : The term '-f' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." My grok filter is set up with an example i have seen on the internet, could i take out the grok filter?. All I want to do is get data feeds into kibana once i have that working i will research how to manipulate data.

Comment: I have used the a tutorial and downloaded a ELK stack instalation which sets everything up.

Comment: Tutorial link : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1083311/ELK-Stack-Install-on-Windows

Comment: The right command to launch Logstash from the shell is [path to Logstash directory]\bin\logstash.bat -f logstash.conf. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: And the grok filter only creates fields from the message, you can remove it at the beginning to test your setup.

Comment: @baudsp thanks it worked. I am getting some output in kibana now.

Comment: @baudsp i have posted another question with an issue im facing logstash after getting Kibana to read a log file. Please see link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958918/config-file-not-getting-read-by-logstash Thank you

Answer (score 2):

try adding following lines to your logstash conf and let us know if there are any grokparsing failures...which would mean your pattern used in filter section is not correct..

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json }
  file { path => "C:/POC/output3.txt" }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.