# Config file not getting read by logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have set up Elk stack on my windows machine with the following :

Elasticserach
Logstash
Kibana

**My logstash.conf**

```
input {
file {
path => "\bin\MylogFile.log"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
output { 
elasticsearch { 
hosts => localhost:9200
}
}
```

**MylogFile.log(Apache Log)**

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326 "http://www.example.com/start.html" "Mozilla/4.08 [en] (Win98; I ;Nav)"
```

When I run **logstash.conf** it creates the following index in elasticsearch :

```
 health  status   index                            
 yellow  open     logstash-2016.10.06
```

The above index is empty and does not get any data from my log file. Please help? I am very new to Elk stack.

When i query the index **logstash-2016.10.10** using: http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.10.10?=pretty=true. I get the following :

```
"logstash-2016.10.10" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "omit_norms" : true
        },
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "message_field" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "index" : "analyzed",
              "omit_norms" : true,
              "fielddata" : {
                "format" : "disabled"
              },
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match" : "message",
            "match_mapping_type" : "string"
          }
        }, {
          "string_fields" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "index" : "analyzed",
              "omit_norms" : true,
              "fielddata" : {
                "format" : "disabled"
              },
              "type" : "string",
              "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                  "index" : "not_analyzed",
                  "ignore_above" : 256,
                  "type" : "string"
                }
              }
            },
```

Comment: If there only one line in you log file, it won't appear in ES. I don't remember if it's because it is expecting a line break or some other reason. Try adding lines to your log file.

Comment: @baudsp I have added more lines to that log, It seems to be generating an index : logstash-2016.10.10 when i query this by using http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.10.10?=pretty=true, i dont get any data from log from log.

Comment: @baudsp, I have edited the my question to give you a better idea, please see above.

Comment: What you get from http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.10.10?=pretty=true is the settings of the index. To check if there's data, you can use http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.10.10/_search?pretty

Comment: Awesome I see the data now, what we be the next step ?Should i filter the data with grok? in order to get a better understanding in Kibana.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your elk stack

Comment: I would like to filter search results. I will do some research on grok filters.Does logstash come standard with the grok plugin? or am i required to install the plugin?

Comment: grok come preinstalled. But you can just filter directly in Kibana in the search bar

Comment: The point of the grok filter is to extract information from plain text logs. For example, from your apache logs, you can extract the html response code to track it. To help you with grok: [grok filter tester](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result), [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and [base grok patterns](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: Thank you for your help @baudsp

Answer (score 0):

try adding following lines to your logstash conf and let us know if there are any grokparsing failures...which would mean your pattern used in filter section is not correct..

```
output {
  stdout { codec => json }
  file { path => "C:/POC/output3.txt" }
}
```

in case you see grok parsing failures :
try a generic expresion in filter section and slowly refine that to correctly parse your logs